# Version control with lightsail

Tags: python, django, amazon-lightsail

I've uploaded the code on amazon lightsail with cloning from github
It's a django
My question is the code works but if i change and commit changes to the repo will i have to re upload and recreate the lightsail instance?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to recreate your Lightsail instance, but you will have to redeploy to your lightsail instance the code.

If you want to automate the process you could look into AWS Code Deploy.  You will not be able to use the Code deploy services for EC2, but you can use the on premise setup.
https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/

It has features that allow for versioning and rollback.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-rollback-and-redeploy.html